# Getting angle value with respect to horizontal axis

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, using the x-y values:

```
     A   B
 1   4   5
 2  -5  -3
```

the slope funcion `SLOPE(B1:B2;A1:A2)` gives `0.88888889` and that value corresponds to `41.6335393` (so, `42°`) with respect to the horizontal axis using the function `DEGREES(ATAN(0.88888889))`.

However, when I use the following x-y values:

```
1  453014
2  785013
3  1117012
4  1449011
5  1781010
6  2113009
7  2445008
8  2777007
9  3109006
10 3441005
11 3773004
12 4105003
13 4437002
14 4769001
15 5101000
```

the `SLOPE` and `DEGREES(ATAN())` functions give `331999` and `89.9998274` (so, `90°`), respectively. The problem is that both lines should have similar angle values because they are relatively similar when plotted (see image below).

Where would it be the problem? Hints are much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: "*Relatively similar when plotted*"? Only as you have chosen arbitrarily unequal scales for the vertical axes.

Comment: I am going to check that, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: confirmed, it is a problem with the scale, thanks @JosWoolley.